# jsoup connect function doesnt fetch html code

Tags: android, jsoup

I have implemented jsoup in android. Jsoup.connect() fetches the html content of a site "http://karnatakatourism.org/" correctly but it doesn't fetch anything for the url "http://karnatakatourism.org/Bidar/en/". I want to fetch the data from the links which are present in html page of www.karnatakatourism.org. Can anyone help me??

Comment: Please remove android related code, this is not important in this question

Comment: I don't understand what the question is about. How are you using Jsoup? If you've specified the URL `http://karnatakatourism.org/` then that is what will be parsed, no other URL's. 

Provide code and be more specific in your question.

Comment: @ Daniel B : My question is that Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.karnatakatourism.org/").get() is fetched correctly. But when i give Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.karnatakatourism.org/Bidar/en/").get() , it doesnt fetch anything...why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that most of the content is loaded by some [AJAX magic](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). You can try to analyze the network traffic to get to the URLs that you are really interested. These might be "getable" via JSoup.connect() then.

Another approach could be the use of other tools like [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp), but I don't know how far you can get with this on the android platform. Probably [selendroid](http://selendroid.io/mobileWeb.html)  could provide your answer.